# Get property from django template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I have a simple tag from which I return `rendered_payload` which has two properties `html` and `reduxState`:

```
@register.simple_tag
def header_and_sidebar():
    user = {}

    # Here's what we've got so far
    render_assets = {
        'url': '/policy-portal/list',#request.path_info,
        'user': user
    }

    try:
        res = requests.post('http://docker.for.mac.localhost:8000/' + 'render', #settings.FRONTEND_URL
                        json=render_assets,
                        headers={'content_type': 'application/json'})
        rendered_payload = res.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        ...

    return rendered_payload
```

when I attempt to use the tag in a template as so:

```
     {% load project_tags %}
      {% header_and_sidebar.html %}
```

this errors out with:

```
Invalid block tag on line 164: 'header_and_sidebar.html'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

How should I go about accessing a nested property?
This setup works fine when I am not trying to access a nested property, so I know it is configured properly for the most part.

Here is my settings.py for good measure:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
       ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'libraries': {
                'project_tags': 'base.templatetags.custom_tags',
            },
        ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the outcome of the template tag in a variable and then access it:

```
{% header_and_sidebar as data %}{{ data.html }}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Despite scanning answers/documentation for 30 minutes, I had not come across that.